# Can I have a field that is populated with values from my Lucene index exclusively?

Tags: glass-mapper, lucene

Sitecore 8.1, Lucene index.

I have a (Glass) field marked with `[SitecoreIgnore]` that I would like to be populated with values from the index.

More specifically, the index has a number of strings that represent GUIDs; I would like this field to be an IEnumerable of Sitecore Items, with their GUID coming from the index. Is this possible out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your index model you can use `TypeConverter` attribute with type `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldEnumerableConverter` parameter to map guids from index to the Items `IEnumerable` in the following manner:

```
public class IndexResultItem : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("_myfield")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldEnumerableConverter))]
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrei! Thanks for your answer - are you sure this works with Glass wrappers? In my experience it only does with Guids and not more complex types.

Comment: Welcome, Emanuele Ciriachi. No, this is not actually a part of the glassmapper, this is a part of Lucene search, as  glassmapper have no relation to the search. So, in your case, I would use glasmapper model and search model separately. In the glass model class you can create a property (not mapped to the sitecore field: with [SitecoreIgnore]) which later will be filled from search model, so, after glass model is created(mapped to the sitecore item) and search is done, you can fill this property : glassModel.CustomItems = indexModel.Items